# How to integrate $m\int_{70}^{100}\frac{vdv}{162+0.354v^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$m\displaystyle\int_{100}^{70}\dfrac{vdv}{162+0.354v^2}$

This is what I have done so far

$u=v^2$

$du=2vdv$

I think this might be where I mess up

$m\displaystyle\int_{100}^{70}\dfrac{du}{324+0.708u}$

I'm not sure what to do from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not try $u=162+0.35v^2$?

Comment: One thing more, the integral in the title does not match the integral in the body

Comment: You haven't changed your limits of integration after making the first substitution: the final integral is NOT equivalent to the one you started with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{v}\right):=\int\frac{\text{v}}{\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot\text{v}^2}\space\text{d}\text{v}\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}=\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot\text{v}^2$:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{v}\right):=\int\frac{\text{v}}{\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot\text{v}^2}\space\text{d}\text{v}=\frac{1}{2\cdot\text{b}}\int\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{\ln\left|\text{u}\right|}{2\cdot\text{b}}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln\left|\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot\text{v}^2\right|}{2\cdot\text{b}}+\text{C}\tag2$$

So, when we have boundaries:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right):=\int_{70}^{100}\frac{\text{v}}{\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot\text{v}^2}\space\text{d}\text{v}=\frac{\ln\left|\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot100^2\right|-\ln\left|\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot70^2\right|}{2\cdot\text{b}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2\cdot\text{b}}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot100^2}{\text{a}+\text{b}\cdot70^2}\right|\tag3$$

When $\text{a}=162$ and $\text{b}=0.354$:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(162,0.354\right):=\int_{70}^{100}\frac{\text{v}}{162+0.354\cdot\text{v}^2}\space\text{d}\text{v}=\frac{1}{2\cdot0.354}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{162+0.354\cdot100^2}{162+0.354\cdot70^2}\right|\tag4$$

For getting a numerical value:

$$\mathscr{I}\left(162,0.354\right)=\frac{1}{2\cdot0.354}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{162+0.354\cdot100^2}{162+0.354\cdot70^2}\right|=\frac{1000}{708}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{37020}{18966}\right)\tag5$$

Answer (score 0):

Use another substitution, $x = 324 + 0.708u$ and $dx = 0.708du$ which results in 
$$m \frac{1}{0.708}\int_{394.8}^{373.56}\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$= m \frac{1}{0.708}[\ln x]_{394.8}^{373.56} $$ 
You can compute the rest